# Windows 7 Speech Recognition and IE 10

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-10, speech

I'm using Windows 7 Speech Recognition with IE 10, and when I say "show numbers" it does not number all the items on my page - only 3 or 4 at most, usually the address bar, minimize, expand and close buttons, but not any of the actual content of the page or tool bars.  Anyone know what is happening?

Comment: Does this happen for all websites?